# Advice about J2ME for Blackberry available IDEs and documentation

Tags: ide, blackberry, java-me, emulation

I am developing standard J2ME apps in NETbeans, but is there any specific IDE and emulator for Blackberry development? Any specific documentation about J2ME for Blackberry ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771705/what-is-the-best-ide-for-development-on-the-blackberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the API Reference for every Blackberry OS. Example [4.5](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/) (just change the Version number to 4.7 or any other version).

But you can find a lot of resources at [the Developer Site](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/) of Research in Motion. Personally I use the eclipse plugin as IDE.

Answer (score 3):

I developed a standard J2ME application in netbeans with about 10 UI screens and using webservices. I was quiet satisfied with the results. I then spent about a week trying to "port" this application to a blackberry. (Trying your approach of getting blackberry api working on Netbeans and trying native J2ME on the blackberry SDK)

I then only managed to get successful results by starting a fresh Blackberry application using the standard blackberry [Eclipse IDE](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp). Although I have two separate applications in different platforms I am happy with this two IDE  approach.

Answer (score 1):

A note of advise when developing for the blackberry: check with the bb API before before using any of the 'advanced' features of J2ME they are far from being all implemented.